# How to prepend to a StringBuilder?

Tags: vb.net, string, stringbuilder, prepend

VB.NET have a method, just like java, to append to an object of type **StringBuilder**
But can I prepend to this object (I mean a add some string before the stringbuilder value, not after). Here is my code:

```
'Declare an array
    Dim IntegerList() = {24, 12, 34, 42}
    Dim ArrayBefore As New StringBuilder()
    Dim ArrayAfterRedim As New StringBuilder()
    ArrayBefore.Append("{")
    For i As Integer = IntegerList.GetLowerBound(0) To IntegerList.GetUpperBound(0)
        ArrayBefore.Append(IntegerList(i) & ", ")
    Next
    ' Close the string
    ArrayBefore.Append("}")
    'Redimension the array (increasing the size by one to five elements)
    'ReDim IntegerList(4)

    'Redimension the array and preserve its contents
    ReDim Preserve IntegerList(4)

    ' print the new redimesioned array
    ArrayAfterRedim.Append("{")
    For i As Integer = IntegerList.GetLowerBound(0) To IntegerList.GetUpperBound(0)
        ArrayAfterRedim.Append(IntegerList(i) & ", ")
    Next
    ' Close the string
    ArrayAfterRedim.Append("}")

    ' Display the two arrays

    lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array before: ")
    lstRandomList.Items.Add(ArrayBefore)
    lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array after: ")
    lstRandomList.Items.Add(ArrayAfterRedim)
```

If you look at the last 4 lines of my code, I want to add the text just before the string builder all in one line in my list box control. So instead of this:

```
 lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array before: ")
    lstRandomList.Items.Add(ArrayBefore)
```

I want to have something like this:

```
lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array before: " & ArrayBefore)
```

Comment: Not very clear what the issue is.  Try `"The array before: " & ArrayBefore.ToString`.

Comment: Stringbuilder has an Insert method, so if you insert at 0 you are pre-pending.

Comment: Why are you redimming the array? What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`StringBuilder.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tyt41s0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prepend to the string builder:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("World")
sb.Insert(0, "Hello, ")
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

This outputs:

```
Hello, World
```

**EDIT**

Oops, noticed @dbasnett said the same in a comment...

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like a lot of overkill to use `StringBuilder` with those `For` loops.

Why not do this?

```
Dim IntegerList() = {24, 12, 34, 42}

lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array before: ")
lstRandomList.Items.Add(String.Format("{{{0}}}", String.Join(", ", IntegerList)))

ReDim Preserve IntegerList(4)

lstRandomList.Items.Add("The array after: ")
lstRandomList.Items.Add(String.Format("{{{0}}}", String.Join(", ", IntegerList)))
```

Job done. Much simpler code.